# Exponential deconvolution using the first derivative

Tags: reference-request, st.statistics, it.information-theory, convolution

There is an interesting observation using the first derivative to deconvolve an exponentially modified Gaussian:

The animation is here at [terpconnect.umd.edu](https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/spectrum/SymmetricalizationAnimation.gif).

The main idea is that if we have an Exponentially Modified Gaussian (EMG) function, and we add a small fraction of first derivative to the original EMG, it results in recovering the original Gaussian while preserving the original area. The constant multiplier is the 1/time constant of the EMG. This is a very useful property.

Has anyone seen this deconvoluting property of the first derivative mentioned elsewhere in mathematical literature? An early reference from the 1960s from a Chemistry paper shows a picture a similar picture. This observation was just by chance, I am looking for a fundamental connection and if the first derivative can be used to deconvolute other types of convolutions besides the exponential ones.

Thanks.
[image: Sharpening by using first derivative]

Ref: J. W., and Charles N. Reilley. "De-tailing and sharpening of response peaks in gas chromatography." Analytical Chemistry 37, (1965), 626-630.

Comment: Deconvolution by adding derivatives is quite a common theme. Actually, one of the earliest methods for sharpening images was to subtract a bit of the Laplacian of the image. If you think a little about it, you realize that this is basically solving the heat equation backwards in time. Doing the same thing with a first derivative is solving an advection equation.

Comment: What I am trying to say is: It's probably to much to say that somebody stole this idea because this idea is around for decades. The adaption to this situation is still some work, but still, the devil is in the details and the idea itself is probably not the biggest contribution. Anyway: You had a good idea - that's good! This indicates that you probably will have good ideas in the future. So, just move on and go on doing good work.

Comment: @Dirk, As someone said the easiest way to be creative is to do lateral thinking.  If we can bring in ideas which are well established in other fields, and apply it to our own field, then that type of work can also be considered new.  Could you further elaborate the part on subtracting the Laplacian? I mean the derivatives becomes a multiplication in Laplace transformation.  I would not say someone stole this 40 year old idea, the annoying part was breach of trust by posting the ideas and scientific discussion in private messages on a public forum with his own name that too without permission.

Comment: It's in the old books like Gonzalez, Woods (look for "Laplacian filter"). Also, not to be confused with the Laplace transform.

Comment: Thank you, there are nice youtube examples. It is based on second derivatives. Interesting idea. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJKgCwUzkmc

Answer (score 1):

Recent literature on the exponential deconvolution technique includes:

[Reconstruction of exponentially modified functions](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333237821_Reconstruction_of_exponentially_modified_functions) (2019)
*"We prove that any function, convolved with exponent, can be reconstructed by adding of its own derivative, multiplied by exponential decay time constant."*

[Exponentially Modified Peak Functions in Biomedical Sciences and Related Disciplines](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5476835/) (2017)

[Comparison of integration rules in the case of very narrow chromatographic peaks](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0169743917305555?via%3Dihub) (2018)

[Reconstruction of chromatographic peaks using the exponentially modified Gaussian function](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/cem.1343) (2011)

Comment: Dear Carlo,  The author of the first link Reconstruction of exponentially modified functions (2019) posted my private communication on ResearchGate without my permission, which was quite inappropriate of him. I had brought this idea to his attention for exponentially modified Gaussians privately. Now it is known that the original idea appeared in 1960s (see original figure).  The main point I am interested is that can the derivative be used to deconvolve any other type of convolution besides the exponential decay?