# Mathematical Techniques to Reduce the Width of a Gaussian Peak

Tags: gaussian, differential-calculus, signal-analysis, convolution

In the chemical analysis by instruments, the signals of several molecules are overlapped which makes it difficult to determine the true area of each peak, such as those shown in red. I simulated this as a sum of six Gaussians (with some tailing elements)

1. One of the simplest technique is to raise the discrete signal values to any positive power (n>0). The standard deviation of the Gaussians becomes smaller and smaller (C, in blue). The big drawback is that we lose all the original peak area information. The transformed data is highly resolved now at the cost of losing true area information.
2. Alternatively, we can add a first derivative of the signal and subtract the second derivative from the original signal i.e., 
   Sharpened signal= Original signal +K (first derivative) - J(second derivative)

K and J are small positive real numbers. This neat "trick" maintains the true area because area under the derivatives is negligible (zero in ideal cases).

Do mathematicians use any other transformations which can make each overlapping peak very narrow, yet maintain the original peak areas. I am not interested in curve fitting techniques at this moment. Any pointers to some similar "peak sharpening" transformations would be appreciated which can resolve overlapping signals.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: related question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/334946/11260

Comment: Stupid question: are you interested in sharpening the peaks for the sake of it or what you really care about is just finding a good approximation to the individual peak areas (and, possibly, the centers)? Also, if I remember my physics right, the resonance peaks are Poisson rather than Gaussian ($\frac{A}{(x-x_0)^2+\omega^2}$). Am I confused here?

Comment: @fedja, it is valid question. I am interested in both. However, an "ideal" sharpening process  should resolve the overlap and maintain the area of original peaks. Sorry, for the confusion, these are not spectroscopic resonance peaks but a simluation of light absorption of six components in a flow cell (=chromatography) by exponentially modified Gaussians.

Comment: So what it the true shape then? The best thing (IMHO) is an intelligent de-convolution (everything else that preserves areas, is translation invariant, etc. is just a more or less crude approximation of it) but the best multiplier to use certainly depends on the shapes of individual signals.

Comment: The true shape of a chromatographic peak is a pure Gaussian. However due to some flow effects, most of the real peaks are modeled by exponentially modified Gaussians (so called EMG peaks). What type of deconvolution are you suggesting?

Comment: Fourier multiplier (it is more or less inevitable if you want something translation invariant). For pure Gaussian a good (in a certain sense optimal in the low noise limit) multiplier family is $e^{\alpha x^2}\Psi(\beta |x|)$ with $\Psi(t)=\frac 1\pi[(\pi-t)\cos t+\sin t]\chi_{[0,\pi]}(t)$ though if you want a peak to remain a monotone (on one side) function, it has to be modified a little. For EMG, I would have to think a bit. If that is something obvious to you, I have nothing to say. If not, I can post my 2 cents :-)

Comment: fedja, I am not a mathematician but a chemist. Could you give a reference to this technique? At least, I am familiar with a technique called Fourier deconvolution (where you divide in Fourier domain), see point number four of the answer below from Tom O'Haver's website.

Comment: I'll post the explanation today or tomorrow, but I want to ask the last stupid question: what is the noise to signal ratio in the data (meaning, say, the maximal inaccuracy divided by the typical peak height)?

Comment: Signal to noise ratio is >10 to 100. Typical peak heights may be 100-500 milliabsorbance units whereas noise is very low in modern absorbance detectors. The sampling rate is >100 Hz.

Answer (score 5):

OK, here are my 2 cents. I'll try to outline the logic and then make a conclusion. We'll start with the Gaussian case.

Suppose that we have a Gaussian peak $f(t)=e^{-t^2/2}$. We want to de-convolve it to the Dirac delta-measure. Since the Fourier transform $\widehat f(s)=\int f(t)e^{-ist}\,dx$ satisfies $\widehat{(f*g)}=\widehat f \widehat {g{,}}$ and the Fourier transform of the standard Gaussian is (up to a constant factor) the standard Gaussian again, the naive but natural idea is just to multiply $\widehat f$ by $e^{s^2/2}$ and to take the inverse Fourier transform of the resulting identically $1$ function.

Unfortunately this is unfeasible as written because of the noise, finite computational precision, etc., so we have to truncate the natural Fourier mulitplier $e^{s^2/2}$ somehow. The idea is to multiply it by some even positive cutoff function $\Psi$ with bounded support. Then the noise will be amplified (on the worst frequency) by
$$
M=\max_s e^{s^2/2}\Psi(s)
$$
but instead of the Dirac point mass, we will get the inverse Fourier transform of $\Psi$. We want that inverse Fourier transform to be as concentrated near the origin as possible. We also want to make it a non-negative function rather than some sign-changing wave. Since we must have $\Psi(0)=1$ to preserve the integral of $f$, we come to the problem of choosing an even function $\Psi$ with bounded support (say $[-\pi,\pi]$; we can always scale later) such that $\Psi(0)=1$, the inverse Fourier transform $\Psi^\vee\ge 0$, and $-\Psi''(0)=\int\Psi^\vee(t)t^2\,dt$ is minimized (other measurements of concentration give slightly different optimizers but pretty much the same results).

This problem is solvable and the solution is the (properly normalized) convolution of $\chi_{[-\pi/2,\pi/2]}(s)\cos s$ with itself, i.e.,
$$
\Psi(s)=\frac 1\pi[(\pi-|s|)\cos s+\sin|s|]
$$
(I'll skip the derivation). Thus, after various scalings, the final family of multipliers is 
$$
H_{\alpha,K}(s)=e^{\alpha^2 s^2/2}\Psi(K^{-1}\alpha s)\,.
$$
and the "peak sharpening formula" is $f\mapsto (H_{\alpha,K}\widehat f)^\vee$.

It turns out that $K=1$ does not noticeably change the picture (but filters out the high frequency noise from the measurements). The noise amplification grows pretty fast with $K$. The corresponding maxima are about
$$
\begin{matrix}
K &\max
\\
1.0 & 1.09
\\
1.1 & 1.55
\\
1.2 & 2.65
\\
1.3 & 5.33
\\
1.4 & 12.4
\\
1.5 & 33.2
\end{matrix}
$$
(with noise at $1$ to $10\%$ of the signal, the higher values of $K$ are pretty useless), so I would recommend setting $K$ between $1.3$ and $1.4$. The whole game is choosing $\alpha$. The legitimate choice is up to the width of the narrowest peak but somewhat higher values are also sort of admissible except you'll get peaks exchanging energy a bit. The rule of thumb is to watch for noticeable negative values in the transformed signal: once they appear, you certainly went too far. Before that moment you are reasonably safe (but not entirely foolproof).

The only difference for EMG is that you want to add one more factor $1+i\beta s$ to your multiplier, i.e., to play with the family
$$
H_{\alpha,\beta, K}(s)=e^{\alpha^2 s^2/2}(1+i\beta s)\Psi(K^{-1}\alpha s)\,.
$$
If $\beta>0$ gets large, it may force you to make $K$ smaller. The effect of going too far in $\beta$ is the same: you'll see noticeable negative values in the transform plus the peaks will noticeably shift to the left. Playing with $2$ parameters is harder than with one and I have no clear advice on in which order to adjust them to get the best results. Just try and let me know what you think.

[image: Successful story].

The original signal is in green, the dots are the actual locations at which EMG's are "centered". Something like that is possible **IF** you can guess one particular parameter right. I still cannot figure out how to teach the machine that guessing.

You'll, probably, like this one too:

[image]

Or this one:

[image]

The current version of the code. This is a dirty homemade contraption, of course, but it is totally automatic.

```
import graph;
access settings;
//settings.outformat="png";


size(500,300,IgnoreAspect);

int sec=seconds();
srand(sec); //Just generates a new picture every time
//srand(1562245957); //was really bad, fixed
//srand(1562264140); //was bad, fixed
//srand(1562265837); //still bad

bool ON=false; //Set to true if you want to see suppressed low values

real beta=0.04; //Noise level (maximum; you need to adjust the code a bit to use the average)
real Beta=0.12; //Cutoff level (approximately 3 times maximal noise)

real K=1.7, L=3, TOL=2.5;  //Don't change these UNLESS
int res=8, dirr=5;//you understand what you are doing


int M=4; //The number of peaks. Set to 1 to see the individual response.

int n=4096; //The sampling range (4096 time ticks with no signal before and after)
real h=1/n;

real QQ=0.07*unitrand(); //Average lambda; set to 0 to see pure Gaussians
real AA=0.15*sqrt(unitrand()); //Average sigma; set to zero to see pure exponentials
real det=unitrand(); //Peak spacing from equidistant det=1 to random det=0

real[] A,Q,X,Y;
for(int m=0;m<M;++m)
{
A[m]=AA*(0.2+unitrand());
Q[m]=QQ*(0.5+0.5*unitrand());
X[m]=det*m/M*n/2+(1-det)*(rand()%quotient(n,2))+quotient(n,8);
Y[m]=0.45+0.55*unitrand();
}

X=sort(X); A=sort(A); //sigma grows with time

real qual(real x)
//deconvolution quality control: the bigger the sum of qual(p[k]), the better.
{
return 
max(x-2*Beta,0)^3-min(x,0)*Beta^2;
}


//write(A); write(Q); pause();

pair[] p, ptemp; 
//p is the (simulated) raw data. It would be interesting to try it on something real.

////////////////Generation of p /////////////////

for(int k=0;k<n;++k) {p[k]=(0,0); ptemp[k]=(0,0);}
p.cyclic=true; ptemp.cyclic=true;

for(int m=0;m<M;++m)
{
pair f(int k)
{ 
return exp(-pi*A[m]^2*k^2)*expi(-2*pi*k*X[m]*h)/(1,2*pi*Q[m]*k);
}
for(int k=-floor(n/2);k<n/2;++k) ptemp[k]=f(k);
ptemp=fft(ptemp);
ptemp/=max(map(abs,ptemp));
ptemp.cyclic=true;
p+=Y[m]*ptemp;
}

real s=0;
for(int k=0;k<n;++k) {s+=p[k].x;}

for(int k=0;k<n;++k) p[k]+=beta*(2*unitrand()-1);


//////////// End of generation of p ///////////////////

//////////// Algorithm begins ///////////////////

pair[] g=fft(p)/n; 

real psi(real t)
{
real s=abs(t);
if(s>pi) return 0;
else 
//return sin(s)/s*(1-s/pi);
return ((pi-s)*cos(s)+sin(s))/pi;
}


pair R(pair x) 
//Suppression of low values. 
{
if (ON) return x;
real y=max(x.x-Beta,0);
if(x.x<0) return (0,0);
else return ((x.x<4*Beta? y*4/3:x.x),x.y)/(1-4*Beta^2);
}

real expp(real x)
{
return 1+x+x^2/2+x^3/12;//A bit more stable than the true exp
return exp(min(x,15));
}


struct T {pair[] p; real u; real q;}

int count=0;

real[] pM; pM[n]=0;
for(int k=n-1; k>-1; --k) pM[k]=max(p[k].x,pM[k+1]);

pair[] pp=copy(p), p1;

T U(pair D, real qq)
{
++count;
write("U "+string(count));



real u=0,v=1;

void proc()
{
for(int kk=0; kk<10;++kk)
{

real w=(u+v)/2;
real a=w*D.x, q=w*D.y;

real b=min(max(a*sqrt(2*pi)/K,2*pi*q/L),1/5);


pair[] G=fft(pp)/n, mult;
p1=copy(pp);

for(int k=0;k<n;++k) mult[k]=(0,0);
mult.cyclic=true;

G.cyclic=true;

for(int k=floor(-n/2);k<n/2;++k) 
{
mult[k]=expp(pi*a^2*k^2)*(1,-2*pi*q*k)*psi(b*k);
if(abs(mult[k])>TOL) mult[k]=TOL*unit(mult[k]);
G[k]*=mult[k];
}

pair[] ppp=fft(G); ppp=reverse(ppp);
ppp.cyclic=true;

bool flag=true;

//for(int k=0;k<n;++k) if(abs(mult[k])>TOL) flag=false; 

for(int k=floor(n*qq-n/res);k<n+n/2/res && flag;++k)
{
if(
ppp[k].x<-0.8*Beta || (k>-1 && k<n && pM[k]<Beta/2 && ppp[k].x>Beta)
) 
flag=false; 
}

if(flag && abs(G[floor(n/2)-1])<1/10^10) {u=w; p1=copy(ppp);} else v=w;
}
}

proc();
p1.cyclic=true;


if(p1[n-1].x>Beta) {write(p1[n-1].x,pM[n-1]); pause();}

real q=0;
for(int k=floor(n*qq-n/res);k<n;++k) q+=qual(p1[k].x); 

T tt=new T;
tt.p=copy(p1); tt.u=u; tt.q=q;

write(tt.u);

return tt;

}




T[] tt;

for(int k=0; k<res; ++k)
{
draw(box((k/res,0),((k+1)/res,1)),yellow); 
pair D=expi(pi/2);
tt[k]=U(D,k/res); real W=tt[k].q;
for(int m=dirr-1; m>-1; --m)
{
D=dir(90*m/dirr);
T ttt=U(D,k/res);
if(ttt.q>W) {W=ttt.q; tt[k]=ttt;}
}
//write (tt[k].u, tt[k].q);
pp=copy(tt[k].p);
}


for(int k=0;k<n;++k)
{
int q=floor(k/n*res);
if(q<1) {pp[k]=tt[0].p[k];}
else
{
real t=q+1-k/n*res;// t=sin(pi*t/2);
pp[k]=((1-t)*tt[q].p[k]+t*tt[q-1].p[k]);
}
}

pp=map(R,pp);
real ss=0;
for(int k=0;k<n;++k) {ss+=pp[k].x;}

write("*************");



path Q=nullpath,  P=nullpath;
for(int k=0;k<n;k+=4) 
{
Q=Q--(k*h,pp[k].x); 
P=P--(k*h,p[k].x); 
}

draw(P,green);
draw(Q);
draw((0,1)--(0,0)--(1,0));
draw(box((0,-Beta),(1,Beta)),red);


for(int m=0; m<M ;++m)
{
dot((X[m]*h,0)); 
pair Z=intersectionpoint((X[m]*h,-20*M)--(X[m]*h,20*M),Q),ZZ=(X[m]*h,Y[m]);
draw((X[m]*h,0)--Z,blue); dot(ZZ,magenta);
}




label(string(sec),(0,0),S);



label("Area ratio="+string(floor(1000*ss/s)/1000),(0.8,1.13),(0,0),fontsize(8));


//pause();
```

Comment: fedja, If I understand your suggestion correctly, basically you wish to broaden the FT of the original signal. Once it is broadened, one can do an inverse transform and recover the "sharpened" peak. Is this the main thrust of this idea? And, could you define what "s" is in terms of time?

Comment: @M.Farooq Yeah, something like that though I really want to divide by an appropriate function rather than just "broaden". I tried to simulate it with and without noise. It works, especially if you combine it with some transformation that merely cuts small values to ignore the stuff that appears on the bottom (like 5-10% of the maximum) and preserves areas up to 5-15% error but it is pretty hard to choose parameters automatically: it tends to overshoot a bit, which is OK, but it also tends to de-convolve with the exponential part even if it is not there. I'll post some pictures, if you want.

Comment: @M.Farooq $s$ is the Fourier variable ("frequency"). Time is $t$.

Comment: fedja, I would be happy to see the figures. Just curious.

Comment: @M.Farooq I posted a "good" one. Failures are also pretty common if the parameters are chosen incorrectly.

Comment: @M.Farooq I posted a couple more. To be honest, the shrunk part is mainly not the Gaussian one but the exponential one. Noisy Gaussians are nearly unshrinkable (I explained why, $K$ in my post has the physical meaning of  the shrinking ratio). Still, you can get some effect even for them, though, of course, not that dramatic. What do you have in reality? Does the smearing come mainly from the Gaussian or from the exponential part?

Comment: Thank you for sharing. This is really interesting. I am curious if the area remains the same after sharpening process or not. Basically you are removing the exponential tail from the Gaussian. Try an interesting experiment. Take the first derivative of your green data (remove noise just for the sake of trial). Now treat the signal as follows= Original signal + (Constant >0)*the first derivative. You will surprisingly get identical results. Keep the constant close equal to the time constant of the exponential. I am still trying to think how your method and this first derivative are connected.

Comment: @M.Farooq The relation is easy: the Fourier transform of the derivative is $is$ times the Fourier transform of the function, so the derivative method is also a Fourier multiplier one. Unlike $e^{s^2/2}$, the function $s$ grows rather slowly, so usually you do not need to tame it if there is no noise. The question is, of course, how far to go. The areas of the peaks are preserved up to the truncated stuff at the bottom (as I said 5-15% accuracy depending on where to truncate).

Comment: Excellent. I "suspected" there must a relation because it is is so similar to this Fourier multiplier method . Okay, let me re-cap to double check your approach in a discrete set of data. You take the FT of the raw data. We will get complex numbers. Next you multiply each complex number by H (s), where we have to choose the value of \alpha\, \beta\, s, and K (last equation). After this multiplication in the Fourier domain, take the inverse transform to get the time series back. I think the most difficult thing is to start from the arbitrary value of \alpha\, \beta\ and s.

Comment: @M.Farooq Yes, the most difficult part is to choose the parameters. Let me ask you one more question: are all peak shapes the same up to the size, or you have Gaussians with various $\sigma$ and exponentials with various $\lambda$?

Comment: In the real world chromatography, $\sigma$ with increases with time rather linearly. However the origin of $\lambda$ is chemical in nature. However, width reduction would be more interesting. There is another nice peak sharpening procedure but it does not retain areas (see the blue curve in the original post). It reduces the width and removes the peak tail. However area info is lost! One can recover it but it is erroneous if the original resolution was poor.

Comment: One more important question, your $s$, would correspond to the frequency scale after FT of the original raw data, right? Additionally, after applying the peak sharpening process, the peak don't look Gaussian. Have we lost the Gaussian character?

Comment: @M.Farooq Yes, $s$ is the frequency scale. I'm a bit confused about the "$\sigma$ increases with time rather linearly" statement. It certainly does not mean that it is much bigger in today's measurements than it was 10 years ago but it still surely means something. Can you explain? My question is pretty much this: when two peaks overlap, may they have significantly different $\sigma$'s or $\lambda$'s?

Comment: @M.Farooq Yes, we lose Gaussianity. If you want to preserve it, you have to honestly multiply by $e^{s^2/2}$ but that is impossible. You lose it with any other method too.

Comment: The chromatogram consists of time vs. detector response as components elute out of the column with a flow of a liquid. Imagine you had a mixture of X+Y+Z. The job of the column is the retard the velocity of X,Y,Z differentially against a constant flow rate of a solvent. Thiw process separates X,Y,Z in time. Assume X,Y,Z come out in this order (Z is in the last with time). Therefore the $\sigma$ (X) <$\sigma$ (Y)<$\sigma$ (Z). We cannot predict $\lambda$. For two overlapping peaks you can assume that $\lambda$ is similar but $\sigma$ of first peak will be smaller than $\sigma$ of the 2nd peak.

Comment: @M.Farooq Ah, OK. That is different from what I thought. The problem with the de-convolution (like with any other linear method) is that it works reasonably well on the narrowest peak but if you try to apply it to a noticeably wider peak, you'll need to change the parameters to get a good result there and the new parameters that do a good job on a wider peak will result in over-de-convolving the narrow peak, which will give negative values there. That is something that has to be compensated for. Let me think a bit :-)

Comment: @Thanks fedja. You may wish to read a mini-article peak sharpening. It explains the motivation. Sorry no equations but it just gives a feel of the current problems. http://www.chromatographyonline.com/progress-peak-processing

Comment: @M.Farooq OK,I posted the code that you may want to play with a bit. The language is Asymptote (it is freely distributed, just google "Asymptote vector graphic language" and follow the source forge net link). Tell me what you think. It is imperfect, of course, but currently it works more often than not.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Asymptote is completely new. I occasionally use Matlab. Do you have a reference to this suggested method? Fourier deconvolution is routinely done by spectroscopists usually by dividing the raw data by an appropriate function (usually Gaussian or Lorentzians) in the FT domain. Of course this is same as to 1/multiplication. Would you agree that that your suggested method is the same?

Comment: @M.Farooq "Would you agree that that your suggested method is the same?" That depends on what you mean by "the same". The only real way to see is to directly compare the two by the results they give. That is up to you because I neither have the real data, nor can run your current programs and I hate Matlab. The code I posted is a bit buggy, by the way (one bug is conceptual and two programming). I'm fixing it now. I found a strange way to de-convolve more and more as you go to the right, as you should  (it is already in the code) but I'm not sure yet how efficient it is.

Comment: @M.Farooq In other words, if you find what I'm saying interesting enough, you'll have to spend some of your time on it too, and if not, why to waste mine? (that is as blunt as I can put it :-) ). I do not know whether something really good will come out of it and guarantee nothing (as it is usual in math) but I'm fascinated with the question enough to try thinking of it for a while ;-)

Comment: Thank you. No your method is certainly interesting, but I have not seen this approach in the chemical literature. I will invest some time to fully understand it. The only draw back I see is that it shifts the peak positions (band positions are very important in chem). One can only understand the code, if and only if, when we are understand the mathematics. This area if signal processing is new and solely based on self-learning. It is very interesting but it not my field. What is your area of specialization?

Comment: @M.Farooq You shift the peaks because you should. The true positions are the dots where the Gaussians are centered, aren't they? That's what you should compare the new peaks to IMHO because $\lambda$'s are an undesirable noise if I got you right. The conceptual bug resulted in shifting the peaks to the left too much though. As to my area, it's Analysis in general and I'll be happy to explain math in details to you if/when you are ready to listen :-) The code can just be run without understanding first to see if it is working better than what you have.

Comment: @M.Farooq " but I have not seen this approach in the chemical literature." I hope not because I'm inventing it on the spot. Otherwise, what's the point of asking a question to a live person? The books are much easier to deal with :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [overview](https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/spectrum/ResolutionEnhancement.html) of peak sharpening (resolution enhancement) techniques:

*1. even derivative sharpening:* $R=Y-k_2 Y''+k_4 Y''''$: works well for symmetric line shapes, reduces the width of a Gaussian peak by 20% and of a Lorentzian peak by 60%

*2. first derivative symmetrization:* $R=Y+k_1 Y'$: converts an exponentially broadened peak into a symmetric Gaussian, and then the width can be reduced via method 1.

*3. power law method:* raise each data point to a power $n>1$: moves the peaks apart, increasing the resolution, to be followed by sharpening method 1.

*4. deconvolution:* effective if the original shape of the peaks has been broadened and/or made asymmetrical by a broadening process that is known or can be measured separately.

Comment: Dear Carlo, Thanks, I am familiar with these ones, the author of this website is my co-author on these methods. I am trying to collect the names of more approaches, if any besides 1-4.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous methods in the context of "inverse problems". Assuming that the Gaussian peaks are generated by a convolution of a "spike train" (i.e. a sum of positive Diracs peaks) with a Gaussian (plus some noise), you can do any of the numerous methods for regularized deconvolution.

Let me just mention variational regularization: Let $g$ be the Gaussian and $\mu$ be the spike train. Then your signal is $f=g*\mu + $ noise. A regularized deconvolution can be obtained by minimizing
$$\|g*\mu - f\| +\alpha\|\mu\|$$
but the choice of norms and the regularization parameter $\alpha>0$ really matter. A simple choice is the $L^2$ norm for the residual and the variation norm (aka Radon norm) for the measure $\mu$. This provably leads to a spiky reconstruction and the process is stable.